# REGEX for Netflix Viewing Activity Titles (TV Show vs Movie using 'Episode')

Tags: excel, regex

I have a csv file containing Netflix viewing data for all users on an account (38k entries) which I am analyzing in Power Bi.

There was no column for Movie/TV which I needed, but its clear that entries with the word 'Episode' in them are episodes from TV shows/Netflix series etc so I created a column in Power Query based on that. Here is an example of what I mean (other columns removed).

| Title | ContentType |
| --- | --- |
| The Office (U.S.): Season 5: Heavy Competition (Episode 24) | TV |
| Forensic Files: Collection 1: A Tight Leash (Episode 2) | TV |
| Kung Fu Panda | Movie |
| Teen Wolf: Season 1: Lunatic (Episode 8) | TV |
| Kung Fu Panda 2 | Movie |

This seems to have worked quite well, but ideally I want a way to be sure I don't have any erroneously labeled entries (e.g "Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV)", not an entry in this dataset, but there is a risk of other 'Movie' titles using this format that I cant manually check for.).

I am a total Regex beginner, and sloppily put together the expression `\b[Ee]pisode[\s\S]\b[^0123456789]` to try and find any entries with the word episode that didn't have a number following it, and all entries were still TV Shows, but this would not account for something like "A New Hope(Episode 4)".

I'm a little stuck now and there are likely other exceptions to the 'Episode' rule that I am not considering. Functionally, the way I have done this is working for my purposes, but I'm trying to show due diligence for anyone that reads my report.

My question: is there a better expression to try that would account for such outliers?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this pattern  [Ee]pisode.[0-9]{1,3}    It give match to all upper lower case + space + up to 3 digits after Episode .

Comment: Powerquery does not support regular expressions :-(

Comment: @xShen This pattern matches 'TV' entries which I am trying to avoid. These entries are being labeled correctly as 'TV', I'm just trying to check for entries like 'Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode 4)' which contain the word Episode with a number following it, but are Movies, not TV shows.

Comment: @Ike That's ok, I am not using Power BI/Power Query for the regex test over the csv, I just mentioned it as that is the environment I am using, and am open to alternative solutions possible in them. I will remove those tags to avoid confusion.